# Prove that maximum value is the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, qcqp

> Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a full rank matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Prove that the maximum value the following optimization problem is the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1}B^{-T}A$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^T A \, x\\ \text{subject to} & \|Bx\| = 1 \end{array}$$

Can you help me with this one?

Comment: What vector norm are you using in the constraint?

Comment: I think it just says that it is a unit vector.

Comment: Unit in what norm? I assume it's the $2$-norm.

Comment: You could introduce a new variable $y:=Bx$. Or use Lagrange multipliers. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It $B^{-1}B^{-T}A$ should be $B^{-T}AB^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=Bx$. Then $x=B^{-1}y$ and the problem becomes: Prove that the maximum value of $y^T(B^{-T}AB^{-1})y$ subject to $||y||=1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-T}AB^{-1}$. It is not hard to attain the conclusion.

Comment: What should I need to show to prove it?

Comment: @Lostinspace, you can use the normal form theory of quadratic forms to prove it.